# Stretched LAN over OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, tunneling

I'm trying to achieve the following but can't find the right information.

I have a Windows server box in a datacenter which has only a WAN connection that I want to integrate in an existing LAN at our office over an OpenVPN tunnel (via internet).

The existing LAN has the range: 192.168.1.x.

I want the server to be reachable at 192.168.1.200.

The VPN tunnel itself is working fine, and I can ping to different machine in both directions, however the server is only reachable at the OpenVPN ip address (10.8.0.1).

The server is the VPN server, the PFsense at the office has been setup as client.

I add 192.168.1.200 on the Windows server in the NIC settings. This doen't work however.

I only found guides to connect two PFsenses, so I'm a bit clueless on how to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with your current OpenVPN configuration, which is using the `tun` interfaces for tunneled mode operation.

You need to change OpenVPN to use `tap` interfaces for bridged mode operation. This way you will have the same L2 network both at your office and at your data center.